# how can I change the style for UISegmentedControl when it is selected by the user in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisegmentedcontrol

This is my `UISegmentedControl` written in Swift:

[image]

I created it with the following code:

```
let selectedAttributes: NSDictionary = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
        NSFontAttributeName: fontForSegmentedControl!
    ]

    let normalAttributes: NSDictionary = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray,
        NSFontAttributeName: fontForSegmentedControl!
    ]

    mySegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedAttributes as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.selected)

    mySegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(normalAttributes as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

and the extension for removing borders is here:

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func removeBorders() {
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.white/*backgroundColor!*/), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: tintColor!), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        setDividerImage(imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    }

    // create a 1x1 image with this color
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:  1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        context!.fill(rect);
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image!
    }
}
```

But there's one thing wrong with it.

When I tap (and hold) the `ONE` or `TWO` it changes the background color to this (for the time it's being touched by user's finger):

[image]

I'm missing some code for changing style for selected (temporary pressed) option in `UISegmentedControl`.

How can I remove the dark grey selection and leave it with clear color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to how you have already set the background image for `UIControlState.normal`, you need to set appropriate images for `UIControlState.highlighted` and `UIControlState.selected` + `UIControlState.highlighted`.

Add the following code to your extension function `removeBorders()` (assuming you want to have a clear background for pressed not selected segment and a tint colored background for pressed selected one):

```
setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: .clear), for: .highlighted, barMetrics: .default)
setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: tintColor!), for: [.selected, .highlighted], barMetrics: .default)
```

Comment: I tried it and it almost works :) now when user presses the option that is not currently selected - it will not highlight in gray, however - there's still a possibility to press the option that is currently selected and it changes background to gray - do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: @user3766930 sure, you can do it, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let normalAttributes: NSDictionary = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray,
    NSFontAttributeName: fontForSegmentedControl!
]

mySegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedAttributes as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.selected)
```

The above code only add gray for selection so change it like below

```
let normalAttributes: NSDictionary = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
    NSFontAttributeName: fontForSegmentedControl!
]

mySegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedAttributes as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.selected)
```